# Intercepted at the Coordinate Axes

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry

A line passes through point $(2,2)$. Find the equation of the line if the length of the line segment intercepted by the coordinate axes of the square root of $5$.

The correct answer among the choices is

$2x - y - 2 = 0$

I am having trouble with interpreting the problem. Particulary trouble with this statement "Coordinate Axes of the square root of $5$". I have no idea what it means and have tried interpreting it as:

$x^2 + y^2 = \sqrt{5}$

or is it:

$x$-coordinate  $= \sqrt{5}$

$y$-coordinate $= \sqrt{5}$

Any Hint? Thanks

Comment: It is your first interpretation:  this by itself doesn't tell you where the axis intercepts are, but only that the distance between them is $ \ \sqrt{5} \ $ .

Comment: Keep in mind, however, that the equation $ \ x^2 \ + \  y^2 \ = \ 5 \ $ is _only_ true for the coordinates of the intercepts.  It is _not_ a general characterization of the points on the line.  You would set up a point-slope equation  $ \ y \ - \ 2 \ = \ m \ ( x \ - \ 2 ) \ $  for the line, find the intercepts for the line and work out the unknown slope from the knowledge of how far apart the intercepts are separated.

Comment: I'll also mention that you will find two such lines are possible because of the symmetry of the geometry (the given point lies on the line $ \ y \ = \ x \ $ ) .  I am presuming that this is a multiple-choice question, so only one of the possibilities is listed.

Comment: Please see this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to format mathematics on this site.

Comment: Correctly stated, the problem should read "A line passes through point $(2, 2)$.  Find the equation of the line if the length of the line segment intercepted by the coordinate axes is $\sqrt{5}$."  The method RecklessReckoner outlined yields the answer $2x - y - 2 = 0$.

Comment: I will mention that one also obtains the line $ \ x \ - \ 2y \ + \ 2 \ = \ 0 \ $ .  The method I describe produces a quartic polynomial with integer coefficients, for which solutions can be found fairly quickly by using the Rational Zeroes Theorem.  The two solution slopes in this problem nicely illustrate a property of the roots of a symmetric polynomial.

Comment: My mistake -- the term I wanted in that last sentence is "a palindromic (self-reciprocal) polynomial".